# .NET Core Web Api Binding Multiple Models

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I try to binding two models into one model. My code has not any error but when I try to post data with postman I get an error.

Here, my first model, the model I binding the two models

```
public class CModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public AModel amodelid { get; set; }
        public BModel bmodelid { get; set; }
    }
```

My second model

```
public class AModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

My third model

```
public class BModel
        {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

I try to get both models id in CModel
But when I try to send a post request from the postman I get this error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "amodelid": [
            "Error converting value 2 to type 'Models.AModel'. Path 'amodelid', line 2, position 17."
        ],
        "bmodelid": [
            "Error converting value 1 to type 'Models.BModel'. Path 'bmodelid', line 3, position 18."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
}
```

The JSON I send with the postman

```
{
    "amodelid":2,
    "bmodelid":1
}
```

And last code quote from Controller

```
        [HttpPost("/api/test/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SomeTask([FromBody] CModel cModel)
        {
            //result return bool
            var result = await _someService.MoreSomeTask(cModel).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (result)
            {
                return Ok("OK");
            }
            
            return BadRequest(new { msg = "Please check your request" });
        }
```

I just only send the controller's code, because even the request doesn't hit my controller (I try to run the program in debug mode so I get this result). Also, I registered my service in a startup.cs file.
Sorry, my question is a little bit long but I try to explain much as can.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because your JSON is incorrect. You are sending:

```
{
    "amodelid":2,
    "bmodelid":1
}
```

Which in C# Class format looks like this:

```
public class ActualReceived 
{
    public int amodelid { get; set; }
    public int bmodelid { get; set; }
}
```

But you state in your CModel class that you want:

```
public class CModel
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public AModel amodelid { get; set; }
    public BModel bmodelid { get; set; }
}
```

Meaning it's failing when you you try to convert `"amodelid":2` to `AModel amodelid` . The issue is your JSON. Since AModel and BModel is an object, you need to use brackets for it.
not tht the input JSON has brackets `{...}`. This identifies it as an object. So taking that into account this is what your JSON needs to look like:

```
{
    "amodelid" : { "id": 2 },
    "bmodelid" : { "id": 3 }                    
}
```

Give that a try and see if it works.